# why is this script's runtime O(n^2)?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I'm going through "Cracking the Coding Interview" by McDowell, and I have a question about one of the algorithms (it is the last program on page 69 of the 6th edition). I wrote it out below using Python. It is supposed to find when a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2 for a,b,c,d being integers from 1 to 1000. Apparently it runs in O(n^2) time. I get that the double loop is O(n^2), but I don't see how to analyze the triple loop that follows. Apparently it is O(n^2) or less but I don't know why.

```
# This algorithm solves the above problem by making a 
# key for every unique a^2+b^2 sum... then the value for each key is
# a list of a,b tuples that I append to every time there is another a,b 
# with a given a^2+b^2 sum.
# Note that since a,b,c,d each on their own can take on any value 
# from 1 to 1000, we don't ever have to create the c^2+d^2 values
# since they will be the same as the a^2+b^2 values (the triple loop
# takes care of that idea).

sum_pair_dict = {}

n = 1001
for a in range(1,n):
    for b in range(1, n):
        sum = a**2 + b**2
        if sum in sum_pair_dict:
            sum_pair_dict[sum].append((a,b))
        else:
            sum_pair_dict[sum] = [(a,b)]

for a_sum, pair_list in sum_pair_dict.items():
    for pair1 in pair_list:
        for pair2 in pair_list:
            print(pair1, pair2)
```

Comment: You have `for` within `for`, each of these iterate `n` times, so effectively you have n*n complexity... The third loop is outside...

Comment: `pair_list` is always a list. But the total number of all these lists are *n* (since you each time in the "generation phase" append a single element). Hence in the "print phase"), yit is still *O(n^2)*.

Answer (score 1):

- The **actual algorithm** is contained in the **first 2 for loops only**. This does the real processing (solving the equation)
- While it is true that **the second** *3 nested for loops* run in O(n^3), they are **just for printin the results**, and not actually doing any processing

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very reasonable question, but some context is needed to see why. The previous four solutions provided by McDowell all `print` the solution as part of solving the equation. For example, one the four previous solutions is:

```
def solve_brute_force(n):
    for a in range(1, n):
        for b in range(1, n):
            for c in range(1, n):
                for d in range(1, n):
                    if a**3 + b**3 == c**3 + d**3:
                        print(a, b, c, d)
```

McDowell's final solution is not really comparable to the previous four solutions, in that it separates printing the solution from solving the equation. So that's not great. But I gets worse:

If the code to `print` the result is removed and we run only the **actual algorithm** (as @molamk said):

```
def solve(n):
    sum_pair_dict = {}

    for a in range(1,n):
        for b in range(1, n):
            sum = a**2 + b**2
            if sum in sum_pair_dict:
                sum_pair_dict[sum].append((a,b))
            else:
                sum_pair_dict[sum] = [(a,b)]

    # just dump the results
    print(sum_pair_dict)
```

Assuming we solve for `n = 4`, we get:

```
{
  2: [(1, 1)],
  9: [(1, 2), (2, 1)],
  28: [(1, 3), (3, 1)],
  16: [(2, 2)],
  35: [(2, 3), (3, 2)],
  54: [(3, 3)]
}
```

This is (IMO) and intermediate format the can be used to derive the solutions. For example, a valid solution is `a=1`, `b=1`, `c=1`, `d=1`. This is not represented in the results (`sum_pair_dict1`). Neither is `a=2`, `b=2`, `c=2`, `d=2`, nor `a=3`, `b=3`, `c=3`, `d=3`.

In fact, there are a lot of results missing, not only those where `a=b=c=d`. To derive these results, the subsequent loops **are required**:

```
for a_sum, pair_list in sum_pair_dict.items():
    for pair1 in pair_list:
        for pair2 in pair_list:
            print(pair1, pair2)
```

Much better, now we see the missing results:

```
(1, 1) (1, 1) <------
(1, 2) (1, 2)
(1, 2) (2, 1) <------
(2, 1) (1, 2) <------
(2, 1) (2, 1) <------
(1, 3) (1, 3) <------
(1, 3) (3, 1)
(3, 1) (1, 3) <------
(3, 1) (3, 1) <------
(2, 2) (2, 2) <------
(2, 3) (2, 3) <------
(2, 3) (3, 2)
(3, 2) (2, 3) <------
(3, 2) (3, 2) <------
(3, 3) (3, 3) <------
```

So, @okcapp, I think this worthy of a correction, which can be submitted at https://careercup.wufoo.com/forms/cracking-the-book-bug-report/